# display records in each subitem in listview in vb6

Tags: listview, vb6

In my program, I used 1st item of listview in sql query with LIKE statement and display result in subitem of same listview. There are total 100 items in 1st column of listview and I want records in subitem of listview. I used checkbox for each item and select all checkbox to display result. When  checked single item and execute query its showing proper result in subitem but when I checked all item and execute query then it's showing same result in each subitem.

ex.

```
query= "select  name from company where product LIKE  '" & ListView1.ListItems(I) & "'"
For I = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.Count
  If ListView1.ListItems(I).Checked = True Then
    List.SubItems(2) = ListView1.ListItems(I).ListSubItems.Add(, , my_Recordset1.Fields(0))
  End If
Next
```

when i execute query its showing same result for all subitem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code that you've put above I think you have got your select in the wrong place.  If memory serves me the ListItems are a 0 based so what you have asked for is the text from the first item in the listview.  Try moving the select code inside the if statement and see if that helps.  It would look something similar to this:

```
For I = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.Count 
    If ListView1.ListItems(I).Checked = True Then 
        ex. query= "select name from company where product LIKE '" & ListView1.ListItems(I) & "'" 
        List.SubItems(2) = ListView1.ListItems(I).ListSubItems.Add(, , my_Recordset1.Fields(0)) 
    End If
Next I
```

That way you will be getting the right information for the list item you are looking at.
While you are changing your code have a look at a for ... each [VB6 For each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243371(v=vs.60).aspx), it is worth a look when you are doing things like this.

---

Going on the comment below you need to put the while inside the for statement so your code would look something like this:

```
For i = 0 To ListView1.ListItems.Count -1
If ListView1.ListItems(i).Checked = True Then 
    sSql1 = "select name from company where product LIKE '" & ListView1.ListItems(I) & "'" 

    my_Recordset1.Open sSql1, Conn1, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic my_Recordset1.MoveFirst 
    While Not my_Recordset1.EOF 
        list.SubItems(2) = list.SubItems(2) & " " & ListView1.ListItems(i).ListSubItems.Add(, , my_Recordset1.Fields(0)) 
        my_Recordset1.MoveNext 
    Wend
End If 
Next
```

I've changed the for statement as well to go from 0, one other little change is to where you are setting the value in SubItems(2) so it will concatenate all of the items and not just put the last one you get to in the recordset.

Comment: What is the error?  Is it something to do with index out of bounds.  The code where you populate the list.Subitems(2) should be in the for aswell.  I'll put it in the answer above.